# jQuery - How can I get custom html data value for different URL results

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress

First of all, please forgive that I don't know all the tech terminology.
I'll try to be clear of what I'm trying to achieve.

1 of many Div Trees:

```
<div data-id="5185"> <-- Unique ID
  <a href="xx">
    <div class="xx" id="xx" value="videothumbs">
```

I can get the attribute value from the element DIV with this:

```
var tmb_folder = $('div[value]').attr("value");
```

But this returns the same value for all other element DIV attribute values:

```
   <div class="xx" id="xx" value="videothumbs">  returns videothumbs
   <div class="xx" id="xx" value="videothumbs2">  returns videothumbs instead of videothumbs2
```

How can I get the different value by each DIV?

Comment: i can't get exactly what is your problem, do you mind if you clarify more what you got and what you need exactly ?

Comment: Whoops - hit save and didn't finish the reply. Hmm. OK I have a DIV element that I assigned a changing value like so: <div data-folder="folder1" On another DIV it could be "folder2". How can i get the value with jQuery?

Comment: Hello @illicious. You need to specify attribute name when you are using data function `console.log($('div[data-thumb_folder]').data('thumb_folder'));` but without **data-**. The rest i think you can do in your foreach loop. But still, quite hard to understand what you are trying to achieve on the client side when you said that you have done everything on the php side which is more correct way of delivering html response to the final user. And reparsing DOM tree again and fixing url issues )

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sergey. I found a longer way with PHP but was hoping i could had avoided that with a quick jQuery alteration. Yea my post is very involved and I'll try to keep it brief and simple in the future. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, or a JS problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: I was hoping the JS could get the div value just for that div tree and do the same for other div tree with a different value. That way each div tree that has a different div value, the JS would get to output data according to the particular div tree.